# Async Generator works on babel-node but fails w/ babel-register or build

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-node, babel-cli

Using `babel-node` I was able to run the following code

```js
function timeout(ms = 100) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let id = setTimeout(() => {
                        clearTimeout(id)
    resolve(ms)
  }, ms)
})
}

async function* worker(limit = 10) {
  async function fetch() {
    return await timeout(Math.random() * 1000)
  }

  let low = 0;
  while (low++ < limit) yield await fetch()
}

async function run() {
  const gen = worker(5)
  const results = [];
  for await (const res of gen) {
    console.log('working')
    results.push(res)
  }

  return 'done'
}

run().then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Doesn't work here, but works on the online [Babel REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-2&code=%09function%20timeout(ms%20%3D%20100)%20%7B%0A%09%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%09%20%20%20%20let%20id%20%3D%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%09%20%20%20%20%20%20clearTimeout(id)%0A%09%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(ms)%0A%09%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20ms)%0A%09%20%20%7D)%0A%09%7D%0A%0A%09async%20function*%20worker(limit%20%3D%2010)%20%7B%0A%09%20%20async%20function%20fetch()%20%7B%0A%09%20%20%20%20return%20await%20timeout(Math.random()%20*%201000)%0A%09%20%20%7D%0A%09%20%20%0A%09%20%20let%20low%20%3D%200%3B%0A%09%20%20while%20(low%2B%2B%20%3C%20limit)%20yield%20await%20fetch()%0A%09%7D%0A%0A%09async%20function%20run()%20%7B%0A%09%20%20const%20gen%20%3D%20worker(5)%0A%09%20%20const%20results%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%09%20%20for%20await%20(const%20res%20of%20gen)%20%7B%0A%09%20%20%20%20console.log('working')%0A%09%20%20%20%20results.push(res)%0A%09%20%20%7D%0A%09%20%20%0A%09%20%20return%20'done'%0A%09%7D%0A%0A%09run().then(res%20%3D%3E%20console.log(res)).catch(err%20%3D%3E%20console.error(err)))

As well as when I run it through `babel-node` like:

```
babel-node src/script.js
```

It however fails when I build and run it like so:

```
babel src/script.js --out-file dist/script.js
node dist/script.js
```

and gives me

```
TypeError: iterable[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
```

Using `babel-register` also fails w/ the same error:

```
node -r babel-register -r dotenv/config src/script.js
```

My current `.babelrc` looks like

```
{
    "plugins": ["transform-strict-mode", "transform-async-generator-functions"],
    "presets": ["es2015-node6", "stage-2"]
}
```

using `es2015` instead of `es2015-node6` yielded no benefit

When I looked at the default plugins and presets used for `babel-node` [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node-options) , and looks like they're empty

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`babel-node` (and the online REPL), in addition to handling runtime transpiling, also [requires babel-polyfill](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/d76092b2ddd86ecaa9df2a23610fd86a34ed379b/packages/babel-cli/src/_babel-node.js#L10). You should `npm i -S babel-polyfill` and then `import 'babel-polyfill';` at your program's entrypoint (or in your example, add `-r babel-polyfill` to your `node` args).

Comment: What a boss! Good eye

Only issue is `import 'babel-polyfill';` still gave the same error, but when I stuck it in the args it worked

so:

`node -r babel-register -r dotenv/config -r babel-polyfill src/script.js`

Comment: To use in prod, build like you would normally

and to run `node -r babel-polyfill dist/script.js`